# Why in Struts1 there is Servlet where as in case of Struts2 there is Filter

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2, struts-1

The front-controller was a Servlet but in Struts2, it is a filter. What is the possible reason to change it to a filter?

Comment: wok on you acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 4):

(This is opinion, you'd need to ask the original WebWork authors.)

IMO it's a bit more intuitive to wrap requests inside a filter, since that's what filters were designed for.

There has been debate about the validity of serving resources from a filter. The spec states:

> Filters do not generally create a response or respond to a request as servlets do,
>   rather they modify or adapt the requests for a resource, and modify or
>   adapt responses from a resource.

Some have claimed (particularly some WebSphere support tickets, and occasionally myself before re-reading the spec during an [email thread on the Struts User mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/ykyf3k575jnk6sxx?q=serve%20resource%20from%20filter%20list%3aorg.apache.struts.users/)) that the spec *disallowed* Struts 2's filter usage, but it's clear that nothing disallows their usage in this way.

Filters allow more flexibility in handling other types of requests (forwards, includes, and container errors) by using the `<dispatch>` element under `<filter>` configuration.

Note that originally it *was* a servlet in WebWork--you may be able to look at the commit logs to ferret out a reason whenever it was the change occurred, but it was quite awhile ago, on the order of 7+ years.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the introducing Interceptors in struts2. It becomes necessary for Struts2 contributors to have main controllers from the front so that a user can not breach a threat within the Java EE pattern. However Struts2 dispatchers are built on the top of the hierarchy of the servlet but it reduces a lot effort from the security point of view.

Reasons:

1. Provide a centralized controller to a framework.
2. To have interceptors and context which can dance on your fingers.

Comment: Interceptors don't require a filter controller; interceptors could just as easily have been run from a servlet (and were, in fact, in the original WebWork). Filters also aren't necessary to provide a centralized controller, for example, Struts 1 and Spring MVC both use a servlet as their centralized controllers.

Answer (score -1):

There are three possibilities why filter is designated as front controller in Strtus2

1. Servlet made as front controller needs developer to provide a
   right value in which lets the framework to initialize many important
   aspects( viz. struts configuration file)as the container starts. In
   absence of which the framework gets initialized only as the first
   request hits.Struts2 makes our life easy by providing
   front-controller as a filter and by nature the filters in web.xml
   gets initialized automatically as the container starts. There is no
   need of such load-on-startup tag.
2. The second but important one
   is, the introduction of Interceptors in Struts2 framework. It not
   just reduce our coding effort, but helps us write any code which we
   would have used filters for coding and necessary change in the
   web.xml as opposed to Struts1.So now any code that fits better in
   Filter can now moved to interceptors (which is more controllable
   than filters), all configuration can be controlled in struts.xml
   file, no need to touch the web.xml file.
3. The front controller
   being a filter also helps towards the new feature of Struts ie UI
   Themes. All the static resources in the Themes now served through
   the filter

Comment: Interceptors could just as easily be run within a servlet controller; filters have nothing to do with that. For example, Spring MVC has interceptors, but uses a servlet as its controller. Similarly, a servlet controller could also handle static resource requests (e.g., CSS and JS files for S2 themes).