# Javamelody with Struts 2 . No action mapped for monitoring

Tags: java, struts2, java-melody

I got a Struts 2 , Java 8 web application running on Wildfly 10 and wanted to integrate Javamelody but i am unable to access the monitoring page no matter my configuration in the web.xml and struts.xml

I use the following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
    <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.77.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my web.xml (web-app version="3.0" ) i have the following configuration:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In my struts configuration following

```
<interceptor-stack name="myStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="monitoring"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

and set myStack as default

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
```

When i try to access http://localhost:8080/myapp/monitoring i get following error:
[org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (default task-3) Could not find action or result: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name monitoring. - [unknown location]

I cannot find many resources on the web concerning this issue or configuration with Struts . Any ideas ?

**Note**: I am one step closer, but i don't get why this is happening.
I had to remove all filter that had a url-pattern /* for this to work. 
Is there a workaround on this?  Of course with this configuration i cannot access any of my pages anymore.

Comment: Please include your complete `web.xml`. Filter ordering matters.

Comment: Struts2 treats everything coming into request as an action, and why you don't have a configuration for this? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097463/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javamelody user's guide](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#2-webxml-file) says to write the javamelody MonitoringFilter in WEB-INF/web.xml before your servlet. But in the case of Struts 2, [there is no more servlet and Struts 2 is controlled by a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10582303/119366).

So you have to write the javamelody MonitoringFilter in WEB-INF/web.xml before your Struts 2 filter.

Comment: I have missed this sentence. Indeed that solves the issue. Thank you